# change background color every second

Tags: javascript

```
function change(i) {  
   var doc = document.getElementById("background");  
   var color =[ "black", "blue", "brown", "green"];  
   for(i=0; i<color.length; i++){  
        doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];  
        alert("my color is "+ color[i]);  
/*if (i>=color.length){i=0;}*/  
    }
 }  
setInterval(function changebackground(){change(0)},1000);
```

HI Folks, 
I am trying to change the background color of a div using the code above. The function works as long as the alert is part of it (I introduced the alert to see if the loop was working ). How do I get the function working without the alert. I need to use vanilla js not jquery. Thanks for helping a beginner.

Comment: You call **change** with `i=0` and run through each of the four colors **without waiting for the change to be seen** -should setInterval be inside the `for` lopp? This would make the function show 4 colours for 1 second each, leaving the color green on theirafter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function works fine (without the alert), you're just not seeing it since you're changing the color within a synchronous loop.

Try like this:

```js
var i = 0;
function change() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("background");
  var color = ["black", "blue", "brown", "green"];
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i = (i + 1) % color.length;
}
setInterval(change, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="background">&nbsp</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Using the  modulo % this way is quite new to me.

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using setInterval, there's no need to use a for loop. Try this instead:

```js
var doc = document.getElementById("background");
var color = ["black", "blue", "brown", "green"];
var i = 0;
function change() {
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i++;
  
  if(i > color.length - 1) {
    i = 0;
  }
}
setInterval(change, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="background" style="height: 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: for some reason this didn't work for. I even changed the setInterval (change, 1000); to setInterval (change(), 1000); but it didn't help. I will spend more time on it to figure out why it works here but not for me. Thanks for helping though.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will change background color with a random color every second
Reference : [Change background every second](https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-change-background-color-every-seconds-in-javascript/)

```js
setInterval(
  function() {
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + randomColor;
  }, 1000);
```

Here is the full HTML example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Change bg color every 1 seconds</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Background Color is being changed every 1 seconds</h1>
<script>
setInterval(
function () {
  var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#"+randomColor;
},1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made [Amit's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3887516/amit) code into a codepen for people to play around with.
https://codepen.io/Saxo_Broko/pen/eYOWJYr

```
var i = 0;
function change() {
  var doc = document.getElementById("background");
  var color = ["black", "blue", "brown", "green"];
  doc.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  i = (i + 1) % color.length;
}
setInterval(change, 1000);

<div id="background">&nbsp</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Got this from codepen.io which might help you**

```
var div = document.getElementById("background");
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

function changeColor(){
  div.style.backgroundColor= getRandomColor();
}

setInterval(changeColor,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title></title>
    </head>
    <body id="background">
      <script>var doc=document.getElementById("background"),color=["black","red","green","blue"],i=0;function change(){doc.style.backgroundColor=color[i],++i>color.length-1&&(i=0)}setInterval(change,60)</script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.I have created a function that has:

1. A list of colors
2. A random function that picks a number from the length of the array.

> const random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 0;
> '0' is the start of the list and '4' is the max index of the array.Which can be replaced with array.length as I have done in case your list is long.

3. Then changing the color of the element by using a random number selected.

   var heading1=document.getElementById("2020");

   ```
    change=()=>{
        var colorList=["blue","red","green","brown","orange"];
        var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorList.length) + 0;
        heading1.style.color=colorList[random_number];

    }
    setInterval(change,1000);
   ```