# How to create a looping html changing background image with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My JavaScript script, which is meant to continually change the background image of my HTML page, will not do what it is supposed to.

```
function CB() {
try {
    var p = {
      Pic1: 'Images/CoolPic2.jpg',
      Pic2: 'Images/CoolPic3.jpg',
      Pic3: 'Images/CoolPic4.jpg'
   };
   var l = p.length;
    i = 0;
    while (i < l) {
        setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.backgroundImage = url(p[i]); }, 3000)
        i += 1;
        if (i > l) {
            i -= l;
            }
    }
}
catch(err) {
    alert(err.message);
}
}
```

Comment: p is object... should p be array?

Comment: I only know how to store data this way.

Comment: `p.length` is undefined cause it's an object.

Comment: I tried making p an array, but does not effect anything.

Comment: That's because you're not setting `backgroundImage` correctly. Even if this code works, it won't do what you're expecting it to do. When it leaves the `while`, before 3 seconds of timeout, it will change the background image to the last of the array (Images/CoolPic4.jpg).

Comment: How could I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need while loop. Just use setInterval (this will call the function every 3 secs) instead of setTimeout (this will call once). Try this

```js
function CB() {
    try {
        var p = [
            'Images/CoolPic2.jpg',
            'Images/CoolPic3.jpg',
            'Images/CoolPic4.jpg'
        ];

        var counter = 0;

        setInterval(function(){
            //document.body.style.backgroundImage = url(p[counter++]);
            console.log(counter++);

            if(counter == 3){
                counter = 0;
            }
        }, 3000)
    } catch(err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
}

CB();
```

Answer (score 1):

This way seams ok:

```js
let i = 1; // = 1 because we want to load first color/image onload 
const color = ["black", "blue", "brown", "green"]; //change colors to url's
change = () => {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[i];//change to background= url(color[i])
  i = (i + 1) % color.length;
}
document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[0]; // this will load first collor/image
setInterval(change, 3000);
```

based on: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640607/change-background-color-every-second)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might help!!!

```
var images = [
   'Images/CoolPic2.jpg',
   'Images/CoolPic3.jpg',
   'Images/CoolPic4.jpg'
];

var count = 0;

setInterval(()=> {
   body.style.backgroundImage = 
      "url(" + images[count++] + ")";
   if (count == 3) {
      counter = 0;
   }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.