# Only with CSS, looping 30 images one after another for infinite time creating a burning fire effect

Tags: html, css

sorry if this question repeats another one , but i did not find result for only CSS usage for creating this effect .

I have 30 images , with which i need to create a burning effect ( hence they need to show in the same div content and to loop infinite.

I tried with percentages and with adding the browser prefixes as well. Also with "opacity property and "fade in" , but i get only one image to repeat itself.

```css
.box4 {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.box4 img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  animation-name: myAnimation;
  animation-duration: 30s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
  0% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_1.png)
  }
  5% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_2.png)
  }
  10% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_3.png)
  }
  15% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_4.png)
  }
  20% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_5.png)
  }
  28% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_6.png)
  }
  32% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_7.png)
  }
  36% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_8.png)
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_9.png)
  }
  45% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_10.png)
  }
  49% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_11.png)
  }
  53% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_12.png)
  }
  58% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_13.png)
  }
  62% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_14.png)
  }
  64% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_15.png)
  }
  68% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_16.png)
  }
  72% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_17.png)
  }
  76% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_18.png)
  }
  78% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_19.png)
  }
  82% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_20.png)
  }
  84% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_21.png)
  }
  86% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_22.png)
  }
  88% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_23.png)
  }
  90% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_24.png)
  }
  92% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_25.png)
  }
  94% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_26.png)
  }
  96% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_27.png)
  }
  98% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_28.png)
  }
  99% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_29.png)
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url(../fireImages/fire_30.png)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box4"><img src="assets/fireImages/fire_1.png"></div>
```

I have also tried with creating css class , so the image src not to be the URL , but the class, and still does not work. i am doing ,i guess, everything wrong , but i need somoone to point me in a direction .

Thank you to everyone in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Much interest in your question_ so I searched through  SO and elsewhere online _ I couldn't find anything that does what you're trying to do using only CSS _ As the answer below (and the first comment) suggest_ you will probably need to use a script to make this work

Comment: background-image to img tag?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the background image isn't a property that can be animated via CSS. For that effect, you'll have no other choice just to use a script. Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Comment: This thread should be perfect guidance for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44168556/how-to-create-a-looping-html-changing-background-image-with-javascript

Comment: Thank you  Kornelijus Glinskas  and  Temani Afif . I will try what Temani sent . Can i add additional condituion to you code so that the images are not just two with "@Keyframes change "  , so that i can add at least 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to use the `background-image` property on an `img` element. You can have background-image on am img element, but in that case the background image will be hidden by the actual image, unless it has transparent parts, which it does not in your case. Dispense with the img element and use background-image on a regular div.

Kornelijus is throwing a bit of a curveball when he says that background-image can't be animated. That just means that it can't be changed *gradually*, as it says on the page he links to. The concept of changing a background image gradually doesn't make sense anyway - it is either one image or another.

Run the code snippet below to see the concept in action. I have reduced the number of keyframes, and used inlined images so that you can't actually see the images changing.

```css
.box4 {
    grid-column:2/3;
    grid-row:2/3;
 }

 .box4{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        width: 315px;
        height: 65px;
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        animation-name:myAnimation;
        animation-duration:2s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 }

@keyframes myAnimation {
       0%{ background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzE1IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjY1IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIzMTUiIGhlaWdodD0iNjUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOnJnYigwLDAsMjU1KTsiIC8+PC9zdmc+")}
       20%{ background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzE1IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjY1IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIzMTUiIGhlaWdodD0iNjUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOnJnYigyNTUsMCwwKTsiIC8+PC9zdmc+")}
       40%{ background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzE1IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjY1IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIzMTUiIGhlaWdodD0iNjUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOnJnYigwLDAsMjU1KTsiIC8+PC9zdmc+")}
       60%{ background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzE1IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjY1IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIzMTUiIGhlaWdodD0iNjUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOnJnYigwLDAsMjU1KTsiIC8+PC9zdmc+")}
       80%{ background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzE1IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjY1IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIzMTUiIGhlaWdodD0iNjUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOnJnYigyNTUsMCwwKTsiIC8+PC9zdmc+")}
       100%{ background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMzE1IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjY1IiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSIzMTUiIGhlaWdodD0iNjUiIHN0eWxlPSJmaWxsOnJnYigwLDAsMjU1KTsiIC8+PC9zdmc+")}
 }
```

```html
<div class="box4"></div>
```

I would not recommend doing an animation this way though. A video would be better. Images are not requested until they are first rendered on the page, so if you are referencing external images then they will not have been downloaded in time for the first loop of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both. 
The case is that this is a task with requirements is to make an animation with the 30 images i got , i can also use Sass/Less/Stylus , but i am newly interested in programming and have not yet made  a research on those CSS Preprocessors ( can the animation be made with the preporcessors? )  . Since there are no specific guidance , i can just make a gift out of those image and assign it to the `div`